# UIScreen main bounds does not respect actual device screen size

Tags: ios, storyboard, uikit, uiscreen

I wanted to create a project without any storyboards.

I have deleted the Main and LaunchScreen storyboards.

As usual I added to my applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Now in Project Settings -> General if I leave Launch Screen File empty `UIScreen.main.bounds` is

```
(CGRect) $R12 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 480))
```

And I get the following screen:

[image]

Now if I add something to the `Launch Screen File` field, in Info.plist -> Information Property List a new line with key `Launch screen interface file base name` appears and the bounds are correct. The bounds are correct even if the value is empty.

Why does the existence of `Launch screen interface file base name` affect UIScreen bounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It started in iOS 8.0 when iPhone 6/6plus was released (TheFuquan user commented it started with the iPhone 5 release), in 2014. Back then if you wanted to support such new devices, you would definitely need, as it was required, to add a proper launch screen. Either through static image with different sizes for each devices you support OR through xib/storyboards.

Now, you answered your confusion already. The way to fix that is to provide a proper launch screen/image.

Apple's Human Interface Guidelines (Launch Screen): https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Comment: Actually it started with the first iPhone 5 going from the height of 480 to 568

Comment: What cracks me is that you don't even need to do provide a proper Launch Screen image. As long as the "Launch screen interface file base name" key exists in Info.plist UIScreen can calculate it's bounds

Comment: You either set sets of launch screen images OR provide that "launch screen interface file base name" to the Xcode project settings (or Info.plist, as you've mentioned).